# Multiple when() clauses in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `request('name')` and `request('surname')` that I need to search respectively in 2 columns with this logic:

If `request('name')`:

- `request('name')` in column `name_kanki` or in column `name_romaji`

And if `request('surname')`:

- `request('surname')` in column `surname_kanki` or in column `surname_romaji`.

I only could write the following code to perform the search:

```php
->when($nameSearch, function ($query, $nameSearch) {
    return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $nameSearch . '%')
        ->orWhere('name_kanji', 'LIKE', '%' . $nameSearch . '%');
})
->when($surnameSearch, function ($query, $surnameSearch) {
    return $query->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . $surnameSearch . '%')
        ->orWhere('surname_kanji', 'LIKE', '%' . $surnameSearch . '%');
})
```

Now the problem is that the first `when()` and the second `when()` seem to be connected to each other by OR logic, while I need `AND` logic.

At present when I insert for example only the `name` field, the search works fine, but if I insert both `name` and `surname` I get the results added to each other (`OR` logic).

How can I change this relationship to an `AND` logic (2 filters) that works if both `name` and `surname` fields have been compiled by the `user`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you to achieve you AND condition result. instead of when I try with where method.

```
        ->where(function ($query) use($nameSearch, $surnameSearch) {
            if(isset($nameSearch)){
                 return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $nameSearch . 
              '%')
              ->orWhere('name_kanji', 'LIKE', '%' . $nameSearch . 
              '%');
            }else{
                return $query->where('surname', 'LIKE', '%' . 
                       $surnameSearch . '%')->orWhere('surname_kanji', 
                       'LIKE', '%' . $surnameSearch . '%');
            }
         })
```